# How to change chrome hamburger menu background and text color?

Tags: google-contacts-api

I would like to change the background color #ffffff of the hamburger menu in Chrome browser. In which file which offset do I have to change in hex editor? And know someone where the offsets are for the hamburger  menu and tabs text colors? I wan't to change the black text.

Comment: Details are not clear . Atleast let us know is it for web or for application and share which technology it is .

Comment: It is for the chrome application, i.e. for the right click context menu of chrome.